# OCR tessdata directory is incorrect

Tags: java, maven, directory, pom.xml

I've been following [this tutorial](https://techdora.com/ocr-in-java-how-to-read-text-from-image/) for trying to create an OCR and I've copy and pasted all of the necessary code and followed the steps but I keep receiving this error when I run OCRDemo.java:

> Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata
> Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
> Failed loading language 'eng'
> Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

So I'm assuming the issue is that TESSDATA_PREFIX has the wrong directory. Currently it is "C:\CodeRepository\OCR\tessdata" and I got that directory and confirmed that directory by literally going into file explorer and copying and pasting it. But I keep getting this error message. I've also tried "OCR\tessdata", "tessdata" but none of them work. Help?

Here's my pom.xml code that has the TESSDATA_PREFIX:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>OCR</groupId>
  <artifactId>OCR</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <TESSDATA_PREFIX>C:\CodeRepository\OCR\tessdata</TESSDATA_PREFIX>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given link, it looks like it points the readers to incompatible language data files. Try https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast.

Comment: I replaced my tessdata folder with the one you provided but I got the same error messages

Comment: Be sure to set data path: 

`instance.setDatapath("tessdata"); // path to tessdata directory`

Comment: Oh my gosh that fixed it! Thank you so so much I don't know how i missed that.

Comment: The listed tutorial did not seem to mention that statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();          
        instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\Tux\\Documents\\tessdata");
```

this worked for me without the need for setting environment variables. I just put the language file in the 'tessdata' folder

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I'm on a Linux Mint 21.1. So I needed to set tesseract.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/");